# express.js how do i get the full request path within express when it is behind proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, proxy

Express.js version 4.17
my setup:
proxy(nginx) -> express.js-server (localhost:3000)

my url is: https://example.com/server/xy
Proxy send to express.js-server: localhost:3000/xy

```
server.get('/data.js', async (req, res, next) => {
            console.log("req2", req.host, req.port, req.originalUrl, req.get('host'), req.path);
res.json({"done":"1"})
})
```

results in this log msg:
req2 example.com undefined /data.js example.com:443 /data.js

nginx conf:

```
http {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
        #proxy_set_header Connection        $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host              $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl   on;

     server {
            set $server http://localhost:3000;
                location /server{
                        rewrite ^/server/(.*) /$1 break;
                        proxy_pass $server;
                        proxy_redirect $server https://$host:$server_port/server/;
                }
}
```

An idea how to get that basepath that seems to be lost between proxy and express.js?

Comment: The only thing missing is the `/server` part right ? Given that you have access to it in the nginx config, you can always append it

Comment: I was hoping there would be another option, like the proxy can pass the original hostname on.

Comment: you could set an header with the "server" value